# Joining strings with Take() and Skip() from same List<string>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` called Items the first item in the list will always be like below(already contains the separator):

```
string1\\string1
```

Then the rest of the items will be a normal string without the `separator (\\)`.

I am trying to `string.Join` them all and get the string representation like below.

```
somestring1\\somestring1\\somestring2\\somestring3
```

I am trying something like this, but it is not binding correctly.  What is the correct way of joining these?:

```
string path = string.Join(@"", Items.Take(1), string.Join(@"\\", Items.Skip(1)));
```

UPDATE:

```
var items = new List<string>();
items.AddRange(HeaderCollection.Select(item => item.Header));
var path = string.Join(@"\\", items.ToArray());
```

is producing

```
somestring1\\somestring1\\\\somestring2
```

[image]

[image]

This works if i skip the first item in the list.  No idea what would cause double `\\\\`

```
var header = string.Join(@"\\", items.Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 5):

I would expect to be is as simple as this:

```
  string path = string.Join(@"\\", Items.ToArray());
```

For example, this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        list.Add(@"One\\Two");
        list.Add(@"Three");
        list.Add(@"Four");

        String s = String.Join(@"\\", list.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

> One\\Two\\Three\\Four

Comment: For some reason it is appending \\\\ for any items after the first.

Comment: @user1307149 - Are you certain that the items themselves don't start or end with '\'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood. Is that what you need?

```
string s = list.Aggragate((a, b) => a + "//" + b);
s = list.First() + "//" + s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply that's because the `\` representation in debug mode is like this `\\`. Here is what I mean (attention to the first line `@\` is equivalent to `\\`)

[image]

**Solution**

So you may try this (no need to skip the first one):

```
var path = string.Join(@"\", items.ToArray());  // @"\" not @"\\"
```